# Centralized Rate limiting in Kong using Redis

Tags: redis, rate-limiting, kong, system-design

I'm working on implementing centralized rate limiting in kong using redis, the problem I'm facing is kong fetches the counter from redis first then checks if the rate limit is reached if not then it will increment the counter. Now suppose I have 3 kong nodes sitting after LB and let us assume value for counter key in redis is 5,following this now if a request comes at LB(assuming Round Robin) and this will be routed to first kong node which fetches the value 5 and suppose if another request comes at LB and is being forwarded to kong node 2 and will fetch the same value of 5 before the first node updates the counter. How will I overcome this Issue?

I thought about incrementing the counter and then fetch the value but I think it will add additional latency to the response.

Please do correct me if my thinking is wrong.

Any small help is appreciated.

Comment: Doing a redis call for each request is too expensive for performance.
I recommend to have a background job to sync with redis every x ms. There is no way to avoid a little over limit race condition without adding big latency